# How to add a breakpoint to grid system when looping through data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a break point for the grid system in React while looping through data. It is not behaving the way I want though. I want to have 3 `col-lg-3`, then add a break point with `<div class="w-100"></div>` before proceeding with the same pattern.

I thought it would be fairly easy by attaching the break point if `index === 3`, but since I had to wrap it in another div, it caused some unexpected results.

```jsx
const newVideoRow = category => {
  return category.map((video, index) => {
    if (index === 3) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div className="video col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" key={video.title}>
            <Video
              key={video.title}
              videoTitle={video.title}
              videoLink={video.video}
              videoImage={video.image}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="w-100"/>
        </div>
      )
    }

  return (
    <div className="video col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" key={video.title}>
      <Video
        key={video.title}
        videoTitle={video.title}
        videoLink={video.video}
        videoImage={video.image}
      />
    </div>
   )
  });
};
```

Here is a picture of the unexpected result. Test 4 should be on the next line.

[image: Picture of unexpected result]

The markdown shows the `div` wrapper of both the `col-lg-3` and the `<div class="w-100"></div>`. Could this be causing the problem? If so, how would I change it?

[image: Devtools screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix would be to use Fragments https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html
if you are using react 16.
Dont forget to import it, for example
`import React, { Fragment } from 'react';`

```
const newVideoRow = category => {
  return category.map((video, index) => {
    if (index === 3) {
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <div className="video col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" key={video.title}>
            <Video
              key={video.title}
              videoTitle={video.title}
              videoLink={video.video}
              videoImage={video.image}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="w-100"/>
        </Fragment>
      )
    }

  return (
    <div className="video col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3" key={video.title}>
      <Video
        key={video.title}
        videoTitle={video.title}
        videoLink={video.video}
        videoImage={video.image}
      />
    </div>
   )
  });
};
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks! I do have another question though. I have to use index% 3 === 0 to grab multiples of 3, but it is saying the first one is true as well. Do you know how I would change the code for that?

Comment: Umm, it's a hack :P,
replace 
```if (index === 3) {``` with ```if (!index === 0 && index === 3) {```
If this solve your issue, accept the answer.

Comment: I had to find my own custom solution that involved %. Thanks for all your help!